# Averaging matrix by element

Tags: bash, awk

as an output of a certain program I obtain multiple matrix files(1, 2,.. 10)

I was wondering whether it would be possible to easily select only some matrixes (i.e. 1 and 3), and obtain an average matrix:

```
1 =  2 4 1/  
     1 4 1
2 =  1 2 1/
     1 2 1
average = 1,5 4 1/
          1   2 1
```

I know that this is possible in excel but it is quite time consuming on the long run.

Comment: Please add 4 spaces to the beginning of your code to have it formatted as code. Or highlight the block and hit the little code button at the top. Otherwise your code turns into unreadable garbage.

Comment: Please show the "matrix files" exactly

Comment: Are the backslashes here literal or is that tell us there is a carriage return (which is pretty obvious since the next line is... another line)

Comment: I attach an example matrix:
https://justpaste.it/1jp7r

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Furthermore, could you inform us about your input file format (multiple files or single file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save this script to `col_avg.awk`:

```
FNR==1 && rows {
    # Compute average per column (same as END block)
    for(i=1;i<=cols;i++) {
        if(out) out = out OFS
        out = out (sum[i]/rows)
    }
    print out
    # Reset state for the new file
    cols = 0; rows = 0; delete sum; out = ""
}
#FNR==1 { next }      # uncomment this to skip first line in each file
cols && cols!=NF {
    print "ERROR: not equal number of elements, line: " NR ", file: " FILENAME
    exit
}
{
    rows++
    cols = NF
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        sum[i] += $i
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=cols;i++) {
        if(out) out = out OFS
        out = out (sum[i]/rows)
    }
    print out
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
awk -f col_avg.awk file1 file2 fileN
```

For example:

1.txt

```
2 4 1
1 4 1
```

2.txt

```
1 2 1
1 2 1
```

Command:

```
awk -f col_avg.awk 1.txt 2.txt
```

Output:

```
1.5 4 1
1 2 1
```

P.S. Please, consider choosing "Best answer" if an answer works for you. I see from your history that you never did this before. You should.

Answer (score 0):

Read the matrix as they come, adding the info to corresponding cell and at the end print the sum of each cell divide by the numer of matrix.
I format as float in the print format to avoid too long decimal part like 1/3

```
awk '
     # avoid emply line
   /^$/ {next}
     # start a new matrix (init)
   /^[0-9]/ { Cnt +=1;Row = 0; sub( /^.*= */,""); if( ! Col) Col = NF }
     # add each element to the corresponding cell
   { sub(/\//,"");Row++; for( i=1;i<=NF;i++) M[ Row ":" i ] += $i  }

     # display the result
   END{
     for(R=1;R<=Row;R++){
        for( i=1;i<=Col;i++) printf( "%.2f ", M[ R ":"  i] / Cnt)
        print R<Row ? "/" : ""
        }
     }' YourFile
```

for several files, just replace YourFile witht the list of file. you can also stream your files/batch and pipe the output to the awk